# vue3-google-map: Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vuejs3, quasar

I'm building vue3 app using the Quasar platform. I'm adding page that shows google maps using vue3-google-map. I've followed the docs "Your first map". And it appears to be working...

**However**, In the console i see this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at vue3-google-map:16:36"

The error occurs immediately ... before vite loads my project.

My index.html file is shown below. Do I have the script code in the correct location? If not, where should it be placed?

Any suggestions as to how fix this error?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= productName %></title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="<%= productDescription %>">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width<% if (ctx.mode.cordova || ctx.mode.capacitor) { %>, viewport-fit=cover<% } %>">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="128x128" href="icons/favicon-128x128.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="icons/favicon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="icons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="icons/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico">

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue3-google-map"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- quasar:entry-point -->
  </body>
</html>
```